# how to provide file path from binded directory to program in docker

Tags: python, docker, bind

I have a python code, that works on files. It read files, do something etc.
As an input to the program, you have to provide path to a file.
And here is a question. After I dockerize my program, how it will find a file from host system (outside the container)?
I've read that I will have to bind that host directory with the containter. I think I can handle creation of docker file. My question is simpler. How to pass file from binded directory to a docker file. If I bind `"C:\user\desktop\test\"` directory, and later, if I run docker file with `"C:\user\desktop\test\test.file"` argument, will this work? Or do I have to (somehow) indicate that selected directory is outside the container? Most of tutorials tells that you have to bind directory, but I couldn't find information about how to actualy use files from the binded directory.

Comment: Why have you chosen Docker over Python's native packaging system here?  (A design goal of Docker is that the container filesystems are isolated from the host's filesystem, so it's actively harder to build something that "works on files" in Docker than not.)

Comment: i didn't chose docker. The project requires dockers, and I'm forced to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy a file into the Docker image because it's not going to be changed during the program's usage, use the `COPY` command in the `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY path/to/file/on/host path/to/file/in/image
```

But it looks like you want to dynamically set the file's path at runtime. In that case, don't copy the file or path in the `Dockerfile`. Instead, use a `docker-compose.yml` to run the image built with your `Dockerfile`:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./path/to/folder/containing/file
        target: /path/the/file/will/have/in/container
```